# Convert API response to Data Frame

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, api, request

I have been trying to get data from an API and convert it to a Pandas DataFrame.

However, after reading the data from the API, I'm unable to convert the response to JSON.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/')
x = r.json()
print(type(x))
df = pd.DataFrame(x['teams'])
df
```

error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e2dd33599256> in <module>()
      5 
      6 r = requests.get('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/')
----> 7 x = r.json()
      8 print(type(x))
      9 df = pd.DataFrame(x['teams'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    894                     # used.
    895                     pass
--> 896         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    897 
    898     @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
--> 340             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    341         return obj
    342 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

The API details: https://www.programmableweb.com/api/covid-19-india-rest-api-v10

Comment: have you validated response returned from the get request ?

Comment: 404 response, check if your URL is correct.

Comment: If it gives out JSONDecodeError, it means the response isn't a valid json document